# is this a bug of ios safari?

Tags: ios, css

recently, when using `display:flex` and `flex-grow`, i find a problem:
i write a demo about this question:
[demo](http://output.jsbin.com/nijahifogu)
i run the demo using mac chrome(emulate screen resolution: 320*480) 
and ios (lastest) safari,
the result of chrome is what i expected
the screen shot of results below:
the result of safari:
[image]
the result of chrome:
[image]

---

**update:**

---

A new [demo](http://jsbin.com/kogijutiti/1) that the css property is prefixed by(`-webit-`),
 but it don't work for me.

---

**update:**

---

the viewport need enough narrow to trigger the `text-overflow:ellipse`,
the bug would occur;

Comment: AFAIK, Safari still needs vendor prefixes for flexbox properties.

Comment: Yep, was just about to say that.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara i try to add `-webkit-` prefix, but it does not work;

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxNKqK How about this, works for me? (Using autoprefixer)